# How to return the file number from bag of words

Tags: scikit-learn

I am working with `CountVectorizer` from the sklearn, I want to know how I will access or extract the file number, these what I try
like from the out put: `(1 ,12 ) 1`
I want only the 1 which represent the file number

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()
string1="these is my first statment in vectorizer"
string2="hello every one i like the place here"
string3="i am going to school every day day like the student in my school"
email_list=[string1,string2,string3]
bagofword=vectorizer.fit(email_list)
bagofword=vectorizer.transform(email_list)
print(bagofword)
output:
(0, 3)  1
(0, 7)  1
(0, 8)  1
(0, 10) 1
(0, 14) 1
(1, 12) 1
(1, 16) 1
(2, 0)  1
(2, 1)  2
```

Comment: What do you mean by `file number` ? For instance, if you want the features of the file No 1, you could do  `bagofword[1,:]` which could be easier visualized if you apply `.todense()` to it, `matrix([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])`

Comment: @rth , i mean the order number of the documents (1,12) it represent the feature number 12 appear in document number 1,i want to calculate for each feature all the documents number witch contain the same feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the columns of the sparse array with,

```
features_map = [col.indices.tolist() for col in bagofword.T]
```

and to get a list of all documents that contain the feature `k`, simply take the element `k` of this list.

For instance, `features_map[2] == [1, 2]` means that feature number 2, is present in documents 1 and 2.

Comment: ,thank you it is working for me ,but you mean features_map[2]=[1.2] is feature number 2 is appear in documents 1 and 2.

Comment: @SMO yes, thanks sorry that was a typo in the answer.